# Inheritance on different namespace

Tags: ruby

I have self-writed gem

```
module GemNamespace
  class Foo; end
  class Bar
    def foo
      @foo ||= Foo.new
    end
  end
end
```

Also I have application

```
module ApplicationNamespace
  class Foo < GemNamespace::Foo; end
  class Bar < GemNamespace::Bar; end
end
```

When I call `foo` method at my application it returned me instanceof `GemNamespace` object:

```
bar = ApplicationNamespace::Bar.new
puts bar.foo
=> #<GemNamespace::Foo:0x007f849d8169f0>
```

But I want get object of `ApplicationNamespace` how I can do this without redefine `foo` method

Comment: May be you can tell what you want to achieve by fetching object of your application's `Foo` class and then we can find the best way to do that.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh method Foo & Bar - it's value objects, gem - client to api. That's gem included to few microservices. I want programmers don't expand gem, they should write their functions in microservices.

Comment: What if your ApplicationNamespace class doesn't have a Foo class ? Do you return a GemNamespace::Foo instance ? There is something strange in your code I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is not, that you have several Namespaces, but that GemNamespace::Bar is tightly coupled to GemNamespace::Foo.

You could use something like this:

```
class Bar

    def initialize(klass)
        @klass = klass
    end

    def foo
        @foo ||= @klass.new
    end
end
```

So instead of only ever using GemNamespace::Foo within Bar, you could pass any class.

Answer (score 0):

Your current version of the `foo` method will allways refer to `GemNamespace::Foo` because its context is set at definition (not at execution). Instead you could get the module of the current executing class dynamically. I don't think there is a build-in method that does this so you have to get it manually:

```rb
def foo
    @foo ||= self.class.name.split("::")[0..-2].inject(Kernel) { |s, c| s.const_get c }.const_get("Foo").new
end
```

This will work for any number of nested modules.